# Sens de "agrégatif"

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Quel est le sens du mot "agrégative" dans ce paragraphe qui fait partie d'un texte de Georges BALANDIER intitulé: *Le sexuel et le social. Lecture anthropologique*.

> La sexualité est socialisée ; le partage sexuel des activités traverse tout le champ de la société et de la culture ; la puissance et le pouvoir, les symboles et les représentations, les catégories et les valeurs se forment d'abord selon le référent sexuel. La sexualité a ainsi une fonction **agrégative**, l'anthropologie moderne la manifeste sous la diversité des formes sociales et culturelles.

Answer (score 1):

*La sexualité a ainsi une fonction agrégative*, ...

> La sexualité a ainsi une fonction d'intégration de l'individu dans la société, ...

L'individu n'est plus un être isolé, indépendant, mais assimilé, incorporé dans le groupe, parmi ses semblables, et, ceci par la sexualité.

La sexualité induit une notion sous-jacente de *[cooptation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooptation)* .

Answer (score 1):

agrégative veut dire tout simplement mettre ensemble ou rassembler dans un même groupe des éléments qui ne le sont pas au départ.

Answer (score 0):

Agréger means the following

> Réunir en un tout des parties distinctes : La nature agrège les grains de sable en grès.

With this definition I think it is rather obvious what are the distinct parts that unites.

Comment: "What are the distinct parts that unite"? We would say in English: To bring together different parts into a whole...